# How do I get the position of a relative element?

Tags: jquery, css-position

I have a `div` that has a `relative` position but I need to get the actual `absolute` position in that moment. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `offset()`.

```
var top = $("#myElement").offset().top;
var left = $("#myElement").offset().left;
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GdjLt/)

Answer (score 0):

For JQuery you can use [`offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/):

```
var pos = $(element).offset();
console.log("Left: " + pos.left);
console.log("Top: " + pos.top);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/NVVFM/